# Derivative with respect to a sum of two variables

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative, chain-rule

Let $T>0$ be fixed and let $C:\mathbb (0, T)\times(0, T)\longrightarrow[0, +\infty[$ a function regular as much as you want (say at least differentiable w.r.t. the second time variable and w.r.t. the first if necessary). Theoretically $C(t, \tau)$ has to represent a cost to reach a certain target at a starting time $t$, with a crossing time $\tau$ and with an arrival time given by $t+\tau$. What is the derivative of $C$ w.r.t. the arrival time $t+\tau$?

**Another point that can be helpful.** In the model assumptions, there is the possibility to think to $C$ as the sum of two costs, say $C_1$ and $C_2$, with $C_1$ depending only on the crossing time variable $\tau$ (so $C_1(\tau)$), and $C_2$ depending on the starting time variable $t$ and the arrival time $t+\tau$ (so $C_2(t, t+\tau)$) with the derivative w.r.t. the arrival time variable not depending on the starting time one (say $\partial_{t+\tau}C_2(t, t+\tau)=\tilde C(t+\tau)$).

Can someone help me?

Thank you

Comment: You have a function of two variables $t$ and $\tau$ and you are asking for its derivative relative to the variable $t + \tau.$ Maybe you can write $C(t, \tau) = C(t, t + \tau - t) = \bar{C}(t, t + \tau)$ and take the partial derivative of $\bar{C}.$ Other than that, your question is too broad.

Comment: @WillM. Yes, I am asking for the derivative of $C(t, \tau)$ relative to the variable $t+\tau$. I may write $C(t, \tau)=C(t, t+\tau-t)=C_1(t+\tau-t)+C_2(t, t+\tau)$ but it is not clear to me how to take the derivative w.r.t. $t+\tau$. But, in general, without thinking to $C$ as the sum of $C_1$ and $C_2$, what does it mean taking the derivative of $C$ w.r.t. $t+\tau$?

Comment: Continuing with my comment above: Once you know $C(t, \tau) = \bar{C}(t, t + \tau)$ then the derivative of $C$ w.r.t. $t + \tau$ is $D_2\bar{C}(t, t + \tau)$ where $D_2$ denotes the partial derivative w.r.t. to the second axis.